# Vue.js - Problem with dynamically created checkboxes: checking one checks all and can't pass dynamic data in value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox

I'm having a very tricky problem with dynamic checkboxes in Vue. This is what my code looks like at the moment.

```
     <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Student</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Remarks</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr v-for="(s,index) in c.data['Students']" :key='index'>
        <td> {{s['First Name']}} {{s['Last Name']}} </td>
        <td>                              
         <input type="checkbox" 
           :id="{{s['First Name'] s['Last Name']}}" 
           value="{{student:s['First Name'], status: absent}}" // need to pass object here
           v-model="attendance">
         <label for="absentCheckbox">A</label> 
        </td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
```

The problem is twofold. First, when one check box is selected it selects all of the others as well. Second, I can't figure out how to pass an object dynamically in the `value` attribute of each checkbox. I know the `value="{ student:s['First Name'], status: absent}"` line is completely wrong but I am not sure how to do it or if it's even possible. My attendance array needs to have objects containing both student name and the status values.

The `attendance` array is on the data function as required like this:

```
 data() {
    return {
      attendance: [],
}....
```

Maybe it is not possible to do what I am trying to do so I'd appreciate any tips or advice on how to achieve this. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The `v-model` is bound to the same `attendance` variable for all iterations in `v-for`. That's why changing one entry affects them all (they're all referring to the one `attendance`).

Comment: And to bind an object, use `:value="{student: 'foo bar', status: absent}"`. Use the colon prefix, as you've done with the other bindings. No double brackets.

Comment: To solve the problem regarding the selection You need to give different “name=“ attribute to each checkbox.

Comment: @tony19 Thanks. Sorry, I should have been clearer, I know why it is happening, I just can't figure a way to avoid it. For the problem of passing the object, the main issue is passing a value dynamically instead of hardcoded. like `'foo bar'`. When I try to pass my dynamic student value it gets pushed to the array as a string - i.e. `{ student:s['First Name'], status: absent }`.

Comment: I hard-coded my value only for simplicity. You could use the same syntax to bind your dynamic value.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
value="{{student:s['First Name'], status: absent}}"
```

Is exactly what you hard coded on your iteration, the note that's the reason why all your checkbox are checked on a click.

The values of the checkbox should be unique.

To pass dynamic values to ur input, you should bind them.
E.g

```
:value="object"
// Where object is a valid know JavaScript object
```

**Binding** let's you pass dynamic value to your template.